# Save Bitmap in the phone Storage in Android version > 10

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-bitmap, android-external-storage, save-image

This is my very first post on Stackoverflow so Im really sorry If I'm not doing it the right way.
My problem is that I would like to save a bitmap as an image (.jpg) in the gallery of the phone.
The following code is totally functionnal in any version of Android < 10 but not in a version >=10.. I would like to know if I could adapt this code for the versions of Android >= 10 ? If not do u have any solutions to my problem ?
Thank you very much if you take ur time to read and even answer !

There is my code :

```java
   public void saveTempBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
        if (isExternalStorageWritable()) {
            saveImage(bitmap);
        }else{
            System.out.println("no privilege");
        }
    }
```

```java
    public boolean isExternalStorageWritable() {
        String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
        if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

```java
private void saveImage(Bitmap finalBitmap) {

        String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
        File myDir = new File(root + "/Images_Exportées");
        myDir.mkdirs();

        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        String fname = "ColoriageExporté"+ timeStamp +".jpg";

        File file = new File(myDir, fname);
        if (file.exists())
            file.delete ();
        try {
            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
            finalBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);
            out.flush();
            out.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent(
                    Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
            Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(file); //out is your file you saved/deleted/moved/copied
            mediaScanIntent.setData(contentUri);
            getContext().sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);
        } else {
            getContext().sendBroadcast(new Intent(
                    Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED,
                    Uri.parse("file://"
                            + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));
        }

    }
```

here are the errors I get :

```
W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Images_Exportées/ColoriageExporté20210202_184518.jpg: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:496)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:235)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:186)
        at com.example.coloriage.GalerieParent.saveImage(GalerieParent.java:629)
        at com.example.coloriage.GalerieParent.saveTempBitmap(GalerieParent.java:602)
        at com.example.coloriage.GalerieParent$4$1.onClick(GalerieParent.java:147)
        at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:177)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8178)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:513)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1101)
W/System.err: Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
        at libcore.io.Linux.open(Native Method)
W/System.err:     at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.open(ForwardingOs.java:167)
        at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:252)
        at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.open(ForwardingOs.java:167)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$AndroidOs.open(ActivityThread.java:8046)
        at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:482)
        ... 12 more
```

Comment: When you run this on an Android device with version >= 10 do you run into any errors ? if So could share the error ?

Comment: @ReginaldoCosta I edited my code with the list of the errors. Thanks you for ur help

Comment: `myDir.mkdirs();` Only call mkdirs() if the directory does not exist yet. And if you do check the return value as it might fail. In that case inform the user with Toast() and stop/return. At the moment you are unaware that the directory does not get created.

Comment: `catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }` Display a Toast() to inform the user and stop/return. Now you blindly try to let a non existing file be scanned.

Comment: `if (file.exists())
            file.delete ();` That code is not needed.

Comment: No worries, so this call File file = new File(myDir, fname); it does not create a file if it does not exist, hence your error. One way to achieve that is to do FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream({full path of the file you want to create}); "not the instance of file" and that will create the file you want to write to.